# javascript which prevents the loading of a specific url?

Tags: javascript, url

Is there a javascript that prevents the loading of a link on a page, for example: ads.link.com , www.link.com ?

Does anyone know if it is possible ?

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: event.preventDefault(); doesnt serve this purpose. It overides default event handler with jquery/ other js providers.

Comment: could you give me an example of javascript please Orion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this Jsfiddle for you. Try it with your code.

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/Lexjdgme/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://news.google.com">news.google.com</a><p>
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if(e.target.href==="http://news.google.com"){
         e.preventDefault();
      }
  }, false);
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to remove the link tag, you can make it as follow:

```
// With JQuery
$('.advise').remove();

// Or directly with javascript
var advise= document.querySelector('.advise');
advise.parentNode.removeChild(advise);
```

Another Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lexjdgme/1/

Comment: In my case the link automatically loads on the page, such as an announcement , I would like to block the link to the ad does not appear on the page.

Comment: Do you want to remove the link tag or prevent the loading of the link?

Comment: Okay, but how do I stop charging the lik ' ads.ibdnx.com ' page using js ?

this way?

// With JQuery
$('ads.link.com').remove();

// Or without frameworks
var advise= document.querySelector('ads.link.com');
advise.parentNode.removeChild(ads.link.com);

Comment: No, if you want to stop loading the link (to prevent the link), use the first code I posted. Change "news.google.com" by "ads.link.com", and should work.